# class attributes and subclass relationship in python

Tags: python, class, instance, subclass, super

I have a quick question about class and subclass relationship.

I am trying to make a class and a subclass for simple question, but it made me little confused.

Brief explanation for simple question that I am working on is a shipping cost exercise.

1. Selecting shipping type and weight to calculate the cost of shipping
2. If the customer wants to get an insurance, it will add to shipping cost that was calculated in package class.

What I want to ask is that I would like to create the insurance cost calculation as a subclass, but

If you check my code, the error popped up.

**Is there anyway to call 'self.__shipping' attributes in 'Package' class in 'InsuredPackage' subclass?**

I am so sorry for poor explanation, if you have any question, please comment!!

The result should be

Package without insurance:

weights 4 and shipping method A, $2.00

weights 15 and shipping method T, $2.35

weights 20 and shipping method M, $2.15

Package with insurance:

weights 4 and shipping method A $xxx (adding from package without insurance)

weights 15 and shipping method T $xxx

weights 20 and shipping method M $xxx

Thank you for reading.

```
class Package:


    def __init__(self, weight, shipping):
        self.__weight = weight
        self.__shipping = shipping

    def weight(self):
        return self.__weight
    def shipping(self):
        return self.__shipping

    def cost(self):
        cost_01 = {'A':2, 'T':1.5, 'M':0.5}
        cost_02 = {'A':3, 'T':2.35, 'M':1.5}
        cost_03 = {'A':4, 'T':3.25, 'M':2.15}

        if 1 <= self.__weight <= 8:
            return cost_01[self.__shipping]
        if 8 <= self.__weight <= 16:
            return cost_02[self.__shipping]
        if 17 <= self.__weight:
            return cost_03[self.__shipping]

    def __repr__(self):

            return('The package weights {} and shipping method {} costs'.format(self.__weight, self.__shipping.title()))
            return('The package weights {} and shipping method {} costs'.format(self.__weight, self.__shipping.title()))
            return('The package weights {} and shipping method {} costs'.format(self.__weight, self.__shipping.title()))


class InsuredPackage(Package):
    def __init__(self, weight, shipping):
        self.__weight = weight
        self.__shipping = shipping




print('Package without insurance:')
package01 = Package(10, 'A')
print(package01, package01.cost())

package02 = Package(15, 'T')
print(package02, package02.cost())

package03 = Package(20, 'M')
print(package03, package03.cost())

insurance01 = InsuredPackage(4, 'A')
print(insurance01.cost())
```

Comment: Actually I think you just forgot the additional `__` in your `InsuredPackage` `__init__` function. It works when I add it

Comment: @YiHangTay Thank you! Is there anyway to call shipping result in subclass :(?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Aren't you already doing it in the insured function?

Comment: @YiHangTay So far, my code gave me costs without insurance, so what I exactly want to do next is that I would like to add insurance fee to the costs that I calculated, but I have no idea :(

Comment: So are you asking whether u can use the same __repr__ function to print the cost with shipping in the insuredpackage? Because in your insured function you are already accessing the self._shipping and finding the cost...

Comment: @YiHangTay Yes! and I changed my code little bit, and It gave me an error again :(, could you take a look at it?

Comment: Hi, you can use this `Package.__init__(self, weight, shipping)` to initialise the InsuredPackage. i think you should read up more on Python inheritance and the usage of super